# About the 'minimum triangle' which includes a convex bounded closed set

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Question** : Is the following true?

"Letting $K$ be a convex bounded closed set on a plane, then there exists a triangle $M$, which includes $K$, such that $|M|\le 2|K|$. Here, $|M|,|K|$ is the area of $M,K$ respectively."

**Motivation** : First, I've thought about the case that $K$ is a parallelogram. Then, I reached the above expectation, but I can neither prove this nor find any counterexample. Can anyone help?

**Remark** : If $K$ is a parallelogram, then $|M|\ge2|K|$ for any $M$ which includes $K$. This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534563/about-the-minimum-triangle-which-includes-a-convex-bounded-closed-set) without receiving any answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCircumscribing.html) attributes this theorem to Gross, 95 years ago:

> Gross, W. "Über affine Geometrie XIII: Eine Minimumeigenschaft der Ellipse und des Ellipsoids." Berichte über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Sächsischen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Leipzig, *Math.-Phys.* Kl. 70, 38-54, 1918.

(*Added*). Here is a figure from Wlodek's article, cited in the comments:

     [image: WlodekFig2]

Comment: Moreover, one of the sides of the desired triangle $M$ can be parallel to an arbitrarily chosen line, see:
Kuperberg, W., *On minimum area quadrilaterals and triangles circumscribed about convex plane regions*. Elem. Math. 38 (1983), no. 3, 57–61. MR0703939 (85a:52009)

Comment: Here's a link to Wlodek's article: [journal link](https://eudml.org/doc/141310).